# How to replace a heterozygote?

Tags: java

My question is: how could I replace the "A:A" or "G:T"....(the heterozygote and homozygote in biology)

My code:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < index1.length(); i++){

        if (index1.charAt(i) == 'A:A'){index2 = index1.append('1');}
        else if (index1.charAt(i) == 'G:T'){index2 = index1.append('2');}
```

The " charAt(i) == 'A:A' " and " .charAt(i) == 'G:T' "  show the mistake when I edited the code in eclipse.

I'd like to replace the character of 'A:A' and 'G:T' as a specific number (for example: A:A=1 , G:T=2) in my string, how could I achieve it?
Thanks,

Comment: I'm somewhat confused how a single `char` can equal `A:A`?

Comment: @user3058889 sounds like you want to do String replacements. There are many useful methods available in the java `String` class.  Search for "java String api". [Link for the lazy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you always want to replace `A:A` with `1`, and `G:T` with `2` then you can just use a `String` replace.

```
public void formatString(String input)
{
    return input.replaceAll("A:A", "1").replaceAll("G:T", "2");
}
```

You can chain up as many `replace` methods as you like! You don't need to know exactly where it is. Java will do that for you *(it's clever like that)*. You just tell it what you want to get rid of, and what you want in it's place!

**Just another option**

Your other option is to create mappings between your `heterozygotes` and their respective numbers, using an array implementation. You'd have a field that looks like this:

```
private String[] heterozygotes;
```

In your constructor you could build it:

```
public MyClass()
{
    heterozygotes = {"A:A", "G:T"};
}
```

Now, you've got `A:A` at position `0`, `G:T` at position `1`, so you can use that in your method, as follows:

```
public void formatString(String input)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < heterozygotes.length; x++) { 
        //EG: A:A is as position 0, so replace with 0 + 1 = 1.
        input = input.replace(heterozygotes[x], String.valueOf(x + 1));
    }

    return input;
}
```

That way, all you need to do is add values to your array initialisation, and you'll never need to change the method.

Comment: think the user wanted to replace `A:A` with `1`?

Comment: 1+ for a decent answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is just that, a ***single*** character. You can't throw a bunch together surround them with single quotes and call them a char.

Instead use a String since what is a String but a bunch of chars in a certain order. Get subStrings if need be, and compare with the either `String#contains(...)` or `String#equals(...)` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.